# How do i give curvature to edges in cytoscape.js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I think there is a curvature attribute given to the edges. or should it be given in cytoscape.stylesheet

Comment: Plz check the documentation: http://cytoscapeweb.cytoscape.org/documentation/elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the stylesheet.  Relevant properties: http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/edge-line

Specific properties of interest include the [control point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) properties:

- `curve-style: bezier` for bundled (spaced) curved edges; `curve-style: unbundled-bezier` for complete manual control
- `control-point-step-size` : for bundled bezier spacing
- `control-point-distance` : manual spacing
- `control-point-weight` : to pull the control point more towards the source or target